# Pdf of $Y = X^2$ when $X$ has pdf $f(x) = 2x$ for $0 < x < 1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable with p.d.f. $f(x) = 2x$ for $0 < x < 1$.

Find the p.d.f. $g(y)$ of $$Y = X^2$$

I tried $$G(y) = \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} 2x \,dx = 0$$
which gives me $0$. Then I should take first derivative to get p.d.f. and it is again $0$, but $0$ is not among homework answers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the distribution of $X$ is supported in $[0,1]$, so you shouldn't integrate on $[-\sqrt{y},0]$. Edit: To be more precise, your density on $(-\infty,0)$ is equal to $0$, so you should be  integrating $0-$function there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $0\le X\le 1 \implies 0\le Y=X^2 \le 1$.

Find the cumulative distribution of $Y$ first, namely for $y\in (0,1]$

$G(y)=\Bbb{P}(Y\le y)=\mathbb{P}(X^2\le y)=\mathbb{P}(0\le X\le \sqrt{y}) = \int_0^{\sqrt{y}} 2xdx=y$

and for $y=0$, since $Y=X^2$ is a continuous distribution,

$G(0)=\Bbb{P}(X^2\le 0)=\Bbb{P}(X=0)=0$

so that for $y\in [0,1],\ G(y)=y$